# Networkx: merge list of nodes into a new one conserving edges

Tags: python, networkx

I am aware of the nx.contracted_nodes function but it only takes two nodes to merge.

Is there a simple, concise way of passing a list of nodes, and merge all those nodes into a new one? Here is an example:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([
    ('A','B'),
    ('B','C'),
    ('C','D'),
    ('D','E'),
    ('F','B'),
    ('B','G'),
    ('B','D'),
])
nx.draw(
    G,
    pos=nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot'),
    node_color='#FF0000',
    with_labels=True
)
```

would generate the following graph:
[image: original graph]
Now I would like to be able to provide a list of nodes such as:

```
G2 = nodes_to_collapse(['B','C','D'])
```

and obtain the following graph:
[image: modified graph]
where H is the new node that results from the collapse of B,C and D of the original graph.

Comment: Please add input and expected output

Comment: I think it would be useful to define what the logic behind this collapse is... If you know that writing a function to do it seems pretty straightforward

Answer (score 2):

I think you can easily define a function to do this, but a problem will be how to call the new nodes and how to define the input nodes.... here I am taking a list of nodes and collapse them as a new one (even if there was no edge in the former network between them).

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([
    ('A','B'),
    ('B','C'),
    ('C','D'),
    ('D','E'),
    ('F','B'),
    ('B','G'),
    ('B','D'),
])

def collapse_nodes(G, nodes_to_collapse):
    edges = list(G.edges)
    new_edges = []
    for k,v in nodes_to_collapse.items():
        for n1, n2 in edges:
            if n1 in v:
                n1 = k
            if n2 in v:
                n2 = k
            if n1 == n2:
                continue
            new_edges.append((n1,n2))

    H = nx.DiGraph()
    H.add_edges_from(new_edges)
    return H
        
H = collapse_nodes(G, {'H': ['B','C','D']})
```

Comment: In my case you do not want to "create edges" but only avoid dangling pre-existing ones.

Comment: I do not understand could you clarify?

Comment: I think you are missing the removal of the collapsed nodes and associated edges: `H = nx.subgraph(H, ['A', 'H', 'E', 'F' 'G'])`.

Comment: Also, tuples are valid node identifiers, so the hypernode could be named `('B', 'C', 'D')`, thus avoiding the dictionary function input.

Comment: I agree, with the naming convention but to implement this one should know what the logic is in which the nodes are collapsed in thr first place…

Comment: The graph H looks like the one you wanted in your question…

Answer (score 2):

If `G` is large but you only want to collapse a few nodes, you might not want to iterate over all edges of G. This function collapses an edge `(u,v)` into `u`:

```
def collapse_edge(G,u,v):
  for w,x in G.edges(v):
    if x != u:
      G.add_edge(w,u)
  G.remove_node(v)
```

Then, you can recursively apply `collapse_edge` to edges of the subgraph induced by the nodes that still need to be collapsed.